# "URL not found" error at my localhost setup of TYPO3 website.

Tags: typo3

I have setup TYPO3 successfully on my local server. But I am having problem when clicking on any menu item: It's showing "url not found on server".

When I type in the URL manually into the browser it shows the page. It's only having problems when redirecting after clicking on a page item at any frontend website page.

Comment: typoscript of your config and menu would be nice. Do you use realUrl?

Comment: if so you´d probably have an rewrite problem. make sure to check your .htaccess and rewrite config of your localhost.

Answer (score -1):

That might be related to the domain config or RealURL... or both ;)

Do you use RealURL? Or do you use the standard url config? 
If links to sub pages look like `index.php?id=12345` you are using the standard config.

My guess is that the local DNS ("hosts file") is not configured correctly.
With the hosts file you can simulate how the web site will appear when it's online, hooked up to a "real/global" DNS. (Not quite, but in a nutshell)

So if you set up Typo3 to be reached under http://www.example.com/ you need to tell your local DNS ("hosts file") to route a request to http://www.example.com/ to your local host e.g. http://127.0.0.1/ . In that case your host file needs an entry like so:

```
127.0.0.1 http://www.example.com/
```

What Domain do you enter to reach your web site? Where do the links from the menu link to?

If you wanna know mor about the "hosts file" look here:

http://accs-net.com/hosts/how_to_use_hosts.html

Answer (score -1):

If you can log in into the TYPO3 backend (/typo3/) and can access the frondend through /index.php, but not through the generated menu links, then RewriteRules for mod_rewrite don't apply.

Usually TYPO3's installer should detect this configuration and disable RealURL, which is responsible for generating such nice looking URLs (instead of index.php?id=123). It seems like this failed (or you copied everything afterwards without the .htaccess file?).

Make sure that you have TYPO3's .htaccess file in place in the root directory of your installation. If this is the case, make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled in your Apache config.